# With Kotlin in Android Studio, how to add a list to another list without repeated item by ID in Kotlin way without for loop?

Tags: android, list, kotlin

```
class MyObj {
    lateinit var id: String
    lateinit var name: String
}

var listA : List<MyObj> = [id=1 name=a] [id=2 name=b]  [id=3 name=c]
var llistB : List<MyObj> = [id=2 name=b] [id=3 name=c]  [id=4 name=d]
```

I want get the result listC 
as below

```
listC = listA union listB = [id=1 name=a][id=2 name=b][id=3 name=c][id=4 name=d]
```

Comment: `val listC = (listA + llistB).distinct()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data class MyObj (var id: String, var name: String)

val listA = listOf(MyObj(id="1",name="a"), MyObj(id="2",name="b"), MyObj(id="3",name="c"))
val listB = listOf(MyObj(id="2",name="b"), MyObj(id="3",name="c"), MyObj(id="4",name="d"))
val set = mutableSetOf<MyObj>()
set.addAll(listA)
set.addAll(listB)
val listC = set.toList()
```

This does what you asked but you should need how to write valid Kotlin first. Please take a look at the [tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html).

Also, if you do not want a repeating ID, you should use a map instead of list.